# UI Automator framework for black-box testing would in any case provide bytecode instrumentation of the APK target?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I would like to know whether using the UI Automator framework in black-box testing **always** determines bytecode instrumentation of the APK target or no. I ask this because I want to understand if I can test closed-source applications exploiting the UI Automator APIs also if these use anti-instrumentation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

UiAutomator can be used in black-box testing and can interact with third party applications.

These tests can interact with the device and thus with many applications on it, as opposed to Espresso tests that are intended for your application only, then there's no relationship between them and a particular application or APK.

Comment: Ok, but does not in any way alter the APK of the target application? Forgive me if the question is trivial, but I am new to this field and I am not finding useful and detailed information explaining what the mechanisms behind the test framework are.